# Christoffell symbols manipulations

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Why is it that $$\Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda\tau}\Gamma^\tau_{\mu\nu} = 0?$$

The same goes for $$\Gamma^\lambda_{\nu\tau}\Gamma^\tau_{\mu\lambda} $$which was set equal to zero by the author..

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not zero in general. For example, take flat Euclidean space in two dimensions, in polar coordinates:
$$
ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2
$$
for which the nonzero Christoffel symbols are
$$
\Gamma^r_{\phantom\phi\phi\phi}=-r,\quad \text{and} \quad \Gamma^\phi_{\phantom\phi \phi r}=\Gamma^\phi_{\phantom\phi r \phi}=\frac1r
$$
Then $\Gamma^\lambda_{\phantom\phi \lambda r}=1/r$, and $\Gamma^\lambda_{\phantom\phi \lambda \phi}=0$, so
$$
\Gamma^\lambda_{\phantom\phi \lambda \tau}\Gamma^\tau_{\phantom\phi \phi\phi}=\frac1r\Gamma^r_{\phantom\phi \phi\phi}=-1
$$
for example. Similarly, $\Gamma^\lambda_{\phantom\phi \nu \tau}\Gamma^\tau_{\phantom\phi \mu\lambda}$ can be nonzero in this case: I make it $1/r^2$ when $\mu=\nu=\phi$, and $-1$ when $\mu=\nu=r$.

It's likely that the author of whatever you're reading is talking about a specific spacetime in some specific set of coordinates, and has computed these, which just happen to be zero in that case.

Comment: That was it! I thought he intended to say that this applies in general!